# Create and download a zip with multiple files without saving the zip file on the server (PHP and laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, download, zip

I have several files on my Laravel server. I can already download each of them individually. However I would like to compress many files into a zip file and just download the zip file.

I know I can create a new zip file in my database and add all the files, but I prefer not to keep the zip file on the database, as it would occupy too much space.

Ideally the server would create the zip file when the user clicks on the button on the User Interface (website) and download it without storing it on the server.

A possible solution would be to store the zip and delete it after 10 minutes, for example, but I can't be sure if it has already been downloaded.

Can you think of a better way to do this?

Comment: how big are we talking? Pretty sure you could define the zip in memory and then "save" it to the PHP output instead of disk. There are probably libraries already which can do that.

Comment: the 10 minute idea is not unreasonable though, I've seen other sites which do a download time limit, the user gets a link to download it and told what time it will expire. Yes you can't necessarily be sure it's been downloaded (although you can log when they visit the link to _start_ the download), but that's kind of the user's responsibility. They can always re-generate the link if it expires.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function profilesPdfGenerate(Request $request){
$pdfFiles = [];
$time = time();
if(count($request->selectedIds)){
 $profiles = Profile::whereIn('id',$request->selectedIds)->get();
}else{
 $profiles = Profile::get();
}
foreach($profiles as $key => $profile){
 $view = view('admin.profiles.index-pdf')->with(compact('profile'));
 $html = $view->render();
 $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
 $customPaper = array(0,0,900,900);
 $sheet = $pdf->setPaper($customPaper, 'landscape');
 $pdfFiles[$profile->first_name.'-'.$profile->last_name.'-'.$key.'.pdf'] = $sheet->output();
}
$zip = new ZipArchive;
/* Create a temporary file for the zip */
$zipPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'profiles');
if ($zip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
 foreach ($pdfFiles as $fileName => $pdfData) {
 $zip->addFromString($fileName, $pdfData);
}
 $zip->close();
 $base64Zip = base64_encode(file_get_contents($zipPath));
 return response()->json(['base64_zip' => $base64Zip]);
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create zip file'], 500);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Route and Controller Method:
Define a route in your web.php file.
Create a controller method that will handle the zip file creation and streaming.

```
// routes/web.php  
Route::get('/download-zip', 'ZipController@downloadZip');
```

Create the Controller:
Generate a new controller using Artisan command.

```
php artisan make:controller ZipController
```

Open the generated ZipController.php file and add the following method:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/ZipController.php

use ZipArchive;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ZipController extends Controller
{
    public function downloadZip(Request $request)
    {
        // Get the list of file paths you want to include in the zip
        $filePaths = ['/path/to/file1.txt', '/path/to/file2.txt', /* ... */];

        // Create a unique zip file name
        $zipFileName = 'downloaded_files_' . time() . '.zip';

        // Create a temporary storage path for the zip file
        $zipFilePath = storage_path('app/temp/' . $zipFileName);

        // Create a new ZipArchive instance
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipFilePath, ZipArchive::CREATE);

        // Add each file to the zip archive
        foreach ($filePaths as $filePath) {
            $fileContent = Storage::get($filePath); // Assuming your files are in the storage directory
            $zip->addFromString(basename($filePath), $fileContent);
        }

        // Close the zip archive
        $zip->close();

        // Stream the zip file for download
        return Response::download($zipFilePath, $zipFileName)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
}
```

Configure Temporary Storage:
Ensure that Laravel has write permissions for the storage directory.

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

UI Integration:
Create a button on your user interface that triggers the download.

```
<a href="{{ url('/download-zip') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Download Zip</a>
```

Now, when a user clicks the "Download Zip" button, Laravel will dynamically create a zip file, stream it for download, and delete it afterward. This avoids the need to store the zip file on the server permanently. Adjust the file paths and routes according to your project structure.